# How do I get all the class names and method names of a project?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, code-analysis

I have downloaded a huge project written in Java. I wish to know the Classes and Methods of every class that are available in the project (for further analysis). How can I recover this information. Can I try javadoc in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may ask about changing SVN properties.

Follow this step if that so.

press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>

Select Show view (view : Outline)

then under that u can see all details

Answer (score 0):

I have wrote a custom doclet to list the classname and its methods:

```
public class ListClassAndMethods {

     public static boolean start(RootDoc root) {
            ClassDoc[] classes = root.classes();

            for(ClassDoc clazz : classes){
                System.out.println("Class Name: "+clazz);
                System.out.println("--------------------------");
                for(MethodDoc methodz :clazz.methods()){
                    System.out.println(methodz.name());
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
}
```

> you need to run create a jar of this class and refer it while creating
>   a javadoc using Eclipse IDE

Answer (score -1):

I would extract all the class source files (.java) with find (if you're on a *nix implementation) and create an empty **NetBeans** project with just one package and all the classess inside it. Netbeans will correct the package declaration and you can easily use **autogenerate javadoc** to get a navigable web archive listing all the classes and public/protected methods.

Of course the code may not run anymore but you'll get what you want in minutes.